# Cannot fetch result from a variable in update query

Tags: php, sql, odbc, sap-ase

I'm using odbc to execute queries to Sybase ASE and fetch the results to screen in my PHP code. What I'm trying to do:

```
declare @status char(6)
set @status = 'false'
UPDATE table SET field = 'newvalue', @status = 'true'
select @status as status
```

I'm getting the result using this query in Aquadata, but via php I'm getting nothing.

If I use `SELECT` statement everything works fine. What could cause this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by my own. Should add to my code the following:

```
select @status as status into #isupdate from table;
select * from #isupdate; // make it as a new query;
```